# Border Style in rowcallback in Datatable

Tags: shiny, dt

I want to apply style based on value in column. For example first column has text 'A' and then apply style to the whole row. I tried the same with rowcallback, it works but it does not apply borders. I tried with default datatable border style overriding **border-collapse : collapse**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

css <- "
table.dataTable {
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
}

.lastRow {
  border-top: 1px solid #000 !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: red;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}
"
Clback <- JS(
  "function(row, data, index){",
  "if (data[0] == 'C') {",
  "  $(row).addClass('lastRow');",
  "}}"
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(css))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             DTOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    mydf <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:10], y = sample(1:10))

    output$table <- renderDT({
      datatable(
        mydf,
        rownames = F,
        options = list(
          rowCallback = Clback
        )
      )
    }
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the border properties must be applied to the `td` elements:

```
"  $(row).find('td').addClass('lastRow');"
```